# VB.net System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledbdataadapter

I am using Access 2013 as database in Visual studio 2017. The database is connected and all but when i run this code:

```
myConnToAccess = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database11.accdb")
    myConnToAccess.Open()
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Typ záznamu from Typ", myConnToAccess)
    da.Fill(ds, "Typ")
    Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
    With ComboBox1
        .DataSource = ds.Tables("Typ")
        .DisplayMember = "Typ záznamu"
        .ValueMember = "Typ záznamu"
        .SelectedIndex = 0
        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
    End With
```

I get the **System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Typ záznamu'.'
**

I have the

```
Dim mySQLCommand As OleDbCommand
Dim mySQLStrg As String
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim tables As DataTableCollection
Dim myConnToAccess As OleDbConnection
```

in the begining of the class... also the:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

I dont know what to d any more... can someone please help me?

Comment: Is "Typ záznamu" a column-name?

Comment: Simply put your sql syntax is incorrect. What are you trying to do with the "Typ záznamu"? What is the column name you are trying to read?

Comment: yes the "Typ záznamu" is a column name... i had made it work... 

this line: 
 
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Typ záznamu from Typ", myConnToAccess)

Should look like this: 

da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [Typ záznamu] from Typ", myConnToAccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query the column `Typ záznamu` then you need to put it in square brackets because of the `space` between the words.

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [Typ záznamu] from Typ", myConnToAccess)
```

Comment: yes made it work just a couple of seconds after posting the question but thank you very much

Comment: another question for you. If i have a If statement to find out if the Combobox selected value is a specific string how can i do it if the combobox is filled from database?

Comment: Please create a new question for this with the required details and your last attempt. Also mark the answer you think is the best by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had made it work:

this line:

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Typ záznamu from Typ", myConnToAccess)
```

needs to look like this:

```
 da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [Typ záznamu] from Typ", myConnToAccess)
```

The only difereance is in the column name. it needs to be in squere breaces or how do you call it **[ ]**